# Proving Continuity of Measure from Above

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am currently looking through Bartle's The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure, and am reading the proof of the following theorem:

If $F_{k}$ is a decreasing sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets, and if $m(F_{1}) < \infty$, then $\displaystyle \left(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{k}\right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} m(F_{k})$.

The proof defines $E_{k}:=F_{1}-F_{k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, "so that $\{E_{k}\}$ is an increasing sequence of measurable sets". I find this a bit confusing: Essentially, this sequence consists of everything that is in $F_{1}$ but not in the subsequent $F_{k}$'s. Could somebody please explain to me why this is an increasing sequence?

Also, why is the $m(F_{1}) < \infty$ necessary? Is that just to make sure it's increasing (not sure whether Bartle uses "increasing" to mean "strictly increasing" or just "nondecreasing")?

Comment: If you take less away at each step, then the result is growing. It's like the sequence of real numbers $1-1/n$. The $m(F_1)<\infty$ is required to have $m(E_k)=m(F_1)-m(F_k)$ make proper sense; without that assumption you might be writing $\infty - \infty$. Moreover without that assumption the result may not hold: the situation with $F_k=[k,\infty)$ is illustrative.

Comment: You know $F_7 \supseteq F_8$.  Can you use that to show $E_7 \subseteq E_8$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{F_k\}$ is a decreasing sequence, $F_k\supset F_{k+1}$. So $F_{k}^c\subset F_{k+1}^c$ and 
$$
E_k=F_1-F_k=F_1\cap F_k^c\subset F_1\cap F_{k+1}^c=F_1-F_{k+1}=E_{k+1}
$$
So $\{E_k\}$ is a increasing sequence.